# Modify event handlers as they are created with Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome Extension that sits above a page that I don't control.

The page loads in .js files via Ajax and then subscribes to a PubNub channel. Every time PubNub sends a new message, it writes out something like this:

```
<li>content here</li>
```

It then adds an event handler to the LI.

I would like to modify these event handlers as they are created. Is there a way to do this in a Chrome Extension?

Here is the script that I am trying to add to (this version was run through an unminifier):
http://hostonfiber.com/script.js

I would like the Chrome Extension to inject this code in at line 12432 right above the userClick function:

```
        addToList: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            userpublickey = this.model.get("userpublickey");
            message = e.currentTarget.innerText;
            console.log(message);
        },
```

And then this on line 12397 in the "events: {" section:

```
        "click .message-text": "addToList",
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I've updated the post with code info.